# Make the Windows key react when a context menu is open

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu

On Windows 7, when I press the <kbd>Win</kbd> key, the start menu opens.

However, when a context menu is open, i.e. I performed a right-click on a file in Explorer, I cannot press <kbd>Win</kbd> to open the start menu any more.

Can this behavior be changed so that the context menu closes and the start menu opens?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if you press the windows key, release it and then press the alt key, the context menu will close and the start menu will open. Still an extra key press but maybe a slight improvement.

Comment: I agree, the context menu closes when I press Alt. No way to have it with the Windows key only?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Not saying that there isn't a way but I couldn't find one.